# Alternative To Bell End When Direct-Buried Conductors Enter Conduit

Tags: electrical

I will be powering my garage shortly.  I am direct-burying USE-2 conductors.  300.5(H) requires that there be a bushing to protect the conductors where they enter the conduit underground to come up above grade.  My understanding is that this is normally done with a Bell End.  Unfortunately, I can't find a 2" PVC bell end that's reasonably priced.

What are other code-compliant methods of protecting direct-buried conductors as they enter/exit conduit that I might find?

Comment: I'll reiterate Greg Hill's advice to run wire in conduit the whole way instead of direct burial. It's more expensive _this_ time, but if there's _ever_ a need to make a fix/change, it'll be _much_ cheaper to pull the old wire(s) out of conduit than it will be to dig the trench again, possibly destroying the cable, requiring replacing the whole cable, too.

Answer (score 3):

**These** are conduit bell-end fittings, (sometimes seen as end-bell fitting) for protection of wires where they enter conduit.

[image: 2" conduit bell end fitting image from gordon electrical supply after two places that wouldn't load.] [image: Different 2" end-bell fitting image from emisupply.com]

Widely available for under US $10  in the 2" size, so you need to shop harder, or in different stores/websites.

But if you are dedicated to doing this with some other fitting, to the point that you waste more money you might try to find one of these service entrance cable clamps that admits to being suited to a burial application. That may not exist, (this one says wet, but does not mention burial) it costs more than a bell-end, and you also need a threaded adapter fitting to use it.

[image: Service Entrance Cable Clamp image from Lowes.com]

I also advise not bothering with direct burial, since trenches are expensive and conduit is cheap, but the correct fitting is required if you are going to do direct burial anyway.

Comment: What do you mean by trenches are expensive and conduit is cheap?  A trench digger is $250 a day, but conduit is $4 a foot plus fittings plus whatever apparatus I need to setup to bend it, plus junction boxes to avoid bending more than 360 degrees.  It's there something I'm missing?

Comment: Think about the first time you need to pull another set of wires. You can dig things up again, being careful not to damage the existing run, with all the associated man+hours. Or you can pull wire thru the conduit at no cost beyond the wire itself and be done much faster and without risk to the existing run. Given what you're already spending it's a good investment.

Comment: Conduit is better protection for the wires inside it, so the odds of a problem such as a rock or rodent damaging the direct burial cable are much lower. In many cases wires to go in conduit cost less than direct burial cable. The second time you dig the trench can be completely avoided by using conduit the first time. Not further damaging direct buried cables if redigging the trench is difficult, slow, or both. Few underground conduit runs have much reason to go over 360, but if you have an odd one, then you use a handhole, not a junction box. Enter and leave that with 45 degree bends.

Comment: How often do you guys see direct bury cable fail where the ground doesn't freeze?  It feels like it'd be more worth my effort to put conduit behind the walls in my house than underground.  This USE-2 stuff is pretty tough and there are no rocks where I live.  Is it common practice to bury pex water lines in conduit to protect from rodent damage?  This USE-2 should last at least as long as Pex water line.

Comment: You did not answer the question.